# Power BI M Language?

Tags: powerbi

I am confused how do I translate this to Power BI M Language?

```
case
  when product_code = lower(product_code) and not product_code = upper(product_code)
  then PRODUCT_CODE + nchar(8203
  else product_code end  as PRODUCT_CODE
```

This is part of my query with Product Code being EXlP,  EXLP

Comment: I formatted your question properly. Since I am 100% sure about the syntax feel free to rollback any changes.